# How to get an access token with a private key signed as a JWT

Tags: node.js, keycloak, openid-connect

I want to get an access token from a Keycloak server. The client (in Keycloak) is configured as signed JWT with public and private key and the access token will be used for server to server communication, so there is no user involved directly.  For all I know the grant type for this usecase is "client_credentials" and the auth method is "private_key_jwt". I tried serveral NPM modules to do this and [openid-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openid-client) seems to be most promising. But I can't get it to work.

The problem is that this lib wants the private key not as a signed JWT but as a JWK set. I use the [jose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jose) module for this, but the types are slightly incompatible, so it won't work:

```js
import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';
import { JWK } from 'jose';

public getToken(privateKey) {
    const key = JWK.asKey(privateKey);

    Issuer.discover(
        'https://keycloak.domain/auth/realms/realm-name'
    ).then(
        (issuer) => {
            const client = new issuer.Client(
                {
                    client_id: '<client-id>',
                    token_endpoint_auth_method: 'private_key_jwt',
                },
                {
                    keys: [key], // <-- types incompatible
                }
            );
             client
                .grant({ grant_type: 'client_credentials' })
                .then(token => {
                    console.log('token', token);
                }
            );
        }
    );
)
```

How can I solve this? Or is there another NPM module that better fits this usecase?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was to convert the key to a plain javascript JWK-formatted object:

```
const key = JWK.asKey(jwk).toJWK(true);
```